# How to load List<Asset> from url with Flutter multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14

Tags: image, flutter, assets, picker

I am using Flutter multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14 to upload selected photos to server.
It stores images  List, In my app new insert part is ok, I am getting the selected images and showing them in a gridview and sent them to the server.
But when I try to update my record, I don't understand how to get  my record's images and set them to List. I have the url path of my uploaded images for  that record. I want to get images and convert them to List because multi_image_picker is only accepting Asset, but there is no  obvious explanation in multi_image_picker read me how to do this.

```
  var images = List<Asset>;
  for (var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
        log("image link:" + ad_url + tempList[i].imageDownloadUrl);
        final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(
                Uri.parse(ad_url + tempList[i].imageDownloadUrl))
            .load("");
        final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
        Image img = Image.memory(bytes);
      // in this part I want to convert img to Asset , but I don't know how to do this.
      Asset asset = img....  //How can I do this conversion
     images.add(asset);
      }
```